# Third isomorphism Theorem and Free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F(a,b)$ be the free group on the set $\{a,b\}$, and let $\left<\left<\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}\right>\right>$ and $\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1},a\}\right>\right>$ be the normal closure (conjugate closure) of the set $\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}$ and $\{aba^{-1}b^{-1},a\}$ in $F(a,b)$, respectively.

Given that $F(a,b)/\left<\left<\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}\right>\right>\simeq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ (LHS is a quotient group), I want prove that $F(a,b)/\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1},a\}\right>\right>\simeq\mathbb{Z}$, by using the third isomorphism theorem:

$F(a,b)/\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1},a\}\right>\right>=\frac{F(a,b)/\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}\right>\right>}{\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1},a\}\right>\right>/\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}\right>\right>}$.

Can somebody construct a proper group $G$ that is isomorphic to $\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1},a\}\right>\right>/\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}\right>\right>$ (by using the first isomorphism theorem), so that $F(a,b)/\left<\left\{aba^{-1}b^{-1},a\}\right>\right>\simeq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/G\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ (again, with the first isomorphism theorem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark that $\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1}, a \rangle / \langle aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle \simeq \langle a \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, so the Third Isomorphism Theorem implies 
$$
F(a,b) / \langle aba^{-1}b^{-1}, a \rangle \simeq
\frac{F(a,b) / \langle aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle}{\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1}, a \rangle / \langle aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle}
\simeq \frac{\langle a,b \textrm{ $|$ } aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle}{\langle a \rangle }
\simeq <b> \simeq \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: Are all the $\langle\cdots\rangle$ thingies **normal** subgroup closures?

Comment: Yes, otherwise this doesn't necessarily make sense.

Comment: Then some words explaining why your first isomorphism holds would probably be useful!